# RTSP Link Available on Youtube But missing in Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube Data API version 2.

I am noticing that all of a sudden the RTSP links that were available using the Youtube Data API via the GData feeds are now unavailable in some cases. It is not that these videos in question are not available for mobile devices. These videos definitely have the rtsp links on the youtube website.

I can't find any updates to version 2 pertaining to this sudden change.

An example for the gdata feed that I am using is as below:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Some_Query&author=Some_Author&v=2&orderby=published

Is there something wrong/missing in the above url? Is there any provision in version 3 to make sure that rtsp links are returned as long as they are available on the youtube website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181469/how-to-get-video-rtsp-link-with-youtube-api-v3

Comment: I remind you that API V3 was launched to remove and hide functionality, instead of improving anything. Don't be surprised if in API V4 you can't get video titles or thumbs.