# How to get video RTSP link with Youtube API V3?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I used to get it normally with V2 but what's the alternative in API V3 ?
if not available, is there any hack to do it ? eg. guess the URL ?

Note : V2 is Deprecated now, so i can't depend on it .

Comment: Have you checked this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937903/get-rtsp-url-from-youtube

Comment: All solutions use api v2, you can't have (yet) RTSP with api v3.

Comment: Solution to this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33361766/2706503), solves Similar Question regarding this topic

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is another of the *great advantages of v3 API*. Other *benefits* from this API:

- No more multiple screenshots to choose from
- No more video duration;
  must be requested in second query
- Video duration encrypted in ISO 8601 format to ensure you can't can convert it to seconds

The lack of RTSP value is just another one. I bet that in API v4 they'll probably hide the video title as well, to ensure the API is entirely useless.

Comment: You made me laugh loudly :D

Answer (score 2):

API v3 doesn't return RTSP, your best bet is to implement iFrame player and it will stream the appropriate format for you.

Comment: Iframes won't work on non-Android mobile devices. RTSP is absolutely required and cannot be replaced by cheap tricks like this, anyway I +voted for your good intentions.